# MySQL sorting product codes that have both alpha and numeric characters

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have to sort output of a query for product names where the names have both alpha and numeric characters.

I have already found various solutions that convert the variables to numeric values (+0, etc.), and they sort the numeric part of the product names. But the preceding part of the product name string is of varying lengths, so the names aren't sorted alphabetically:

```
Post Lantern PL1
Post Lantern PL2
Post Lantern PL10
Post Lantern PL22

Landscape Light LV1
Landscape Light LV2
Landscape Light LV10
Landscape Light LV11
```

I guess the shorter names are sorted first?

I want the results sorted naturally: alphabetically, with the numbers in a natural order as well. I have tried:

```
ORDER by CAST(`product_name` AS DECIMAL), product_name
...
ORDER by product_name+0
```

The shorter names get sorted first, even though they are later in the alphabet. The numbers in the last part need to be in numerical order.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. You haven't shown any queries, or listed what you've tried, or how you want them to be sorted.

Comment: @David the miminum would be to state your table schema, sample data, and expected output ;) both `alpha and numerics = alphanumerics`

Comment: Do you have server-side?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a long query doing what you're looking for. I'm not sure about performance, though. You might also want to make some tests on several records to make sure.

```
SELECT
    *
    ,SUBSTRING(
        REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(CONCAT(`product_name`,'8')) AS UNSIGNED)),1,
        CHARACTER_LENGTH(
            REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(CONCAT(`product_name`,'8')) AS UNSIGNED))
        )-1
    ) AS 'numericVal'
FROM `some_table`
ORDER BY
    SUBSTRING(`product_name`,1,CHAR_LENGTH(`product_name`)-CHAR_LENGTH(`numericVal`)),
    CAST(`numericVal` AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

The **8**'s in the `CONCAT()` functions are there for numbers that end with zero(s). Otherwise when you reverse e.g. the string "etc30" and parse the number there it will be **3**, not **03**. So reversing it back will again produce **3** instead of **30**.

You can change those two **8**'s in the `CONCAT()` functions with any single digit(s) (except zeros) you like.

**[EDIT 2]**

Here's the breakdown.

```
# Example record "Post Lantern PL10"...
SELECT
    *
    ,SUBSTRING(                                         # 5a) substring of this is calculated
        REVERSE(                                        # 4) gets re-reversed into "108"
            CAST(                                       # 3) gets casted into an integer so "801" part is parsed
                REVERSE(                                # 2) gets reversed: "801LP nretnaL tsoP"
                    CONCAT(`product_name`,'8')          # 1) is concatenated with an 8: "Post Lantern PL108"
                )
            AS UNSIGNED)
        ),
        1,                                              # 5b) from the first character (index is 1 for this in SQL)
        CHARACTER_LENGTH(                               # 5c) and the length is recalculated (steps 1-4 repeated)
            REVERSE(
                CAST(
                    REVERSE(
                        CONCAT(`product_name`,'8')
                    )
                AS UNSIGNED)
            )
        )-1                                             # 5d1) minus 1 because at the beginning we appended an 8 and we
                                                        # 5d2) want to get rid of it now, so we're dropping the last digit
    ) AS 'numericVal'
FROM `some_table`
ORDER BY                                                        # 6) order by
    SUBSTRING(`product_name`,                                   # 7a) first, substring `product_name`
        1,                                                      # 7b) from the first character
        CHAR_LENGTH(`product_name`)-CHAR_LENGTH(`numericVal`)   # 7c) with the total length - length of numeric part
    ),
    CAST(`numericVal` AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)                      # 8a) then, by the numeric part, which gets casted into
                                                                # 8b) an integer for accurate numeric ordering
```

**[EDIT 1]**

I think the best shot you have (to have total control over the varying data) is to separate `product_name` into 3 columns - `product_name` (like **"Landscape Light"**), `product_class` (or whatever, like **"LV"**) and `product_version` (the numeric part).

Comment: I will try the above solution. I'm not where I can access the site now, but I think the following solution worked earlier. I didn't have time to check thoroughly:

mysql> select f from f order by LEFT(f,1) < 'A', f;
+------+
| f |
+------+
| a0 |
| abcd |
| 012 |
| 02x |
| 0a |
| 3A |
+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

That was solution was here:
http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-240945.html

Comment: @DavidBarrow I don't think that's reliable at all. `LEFT(col,1)` there will put "etc2" after "etc10", where `2 !> 10` in fact. I also edited my answer.

Comment: inhan, I think that worked perfectly. I don't completely understand how it works, since I am a relative beginner. I guess I can go through the terms one by one. If you ever have time to summarize what that code is doing, I sure would appreciate it.

The product names have already been established. To chop them into parts would be cumbersome for data entry later, so I am stuck with the solution above that works with the product names as they are.

Comment: @DavidBarrow I added explanations to the whole code. Hope that makes sense. Let me know if I missed anything there. Still, I can't guarantee anything related to performance here since the engine has some string processing to do and the speed probably depends on the record quantity in this case.

Comment: That is awesome! I totally appreciate that. You have jumpstarted my understanding of this immensely.

Comment: @DavidBarrow No problem. The most critical issue here is adding an additional digit (`8` in my code) and then getting the substring, which makes the whole code longer and look confusing. But I hope I could make it clear why that's necessary - for numbers that end with zero(s).

Comment: The above solution has worked for months, but when the client added "Hanging Lantern CHL13", it put it before "Hanging Lantern CHL1" and "Hanging Lantern CHL2". I'm not sure what changed or why it would put the most recent entry first now.

Comment: Disregard my previous post. The client had added an extra space between "Hanging Lantern" and "CHL13", which caused it to sort first in line. It didn't show up in the browser display, which eliminated the extra whitespace. I found it when viewing the data table directly in mysqladmin. I thought I had trapped/filtered out extra spaces, but apparently not.